# Listing folder content from google drive, returns removed files too

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I use below function to get folder content (files list) from google drive (API V3):

```
def get_gdrive_content(folder_id):
    ret_val = []

    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = service.files().list(q=f"parents = '{folder_id}'",
                                              fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)',
                                              pageToken=page_token
                                        ).execute()

        for file in response.get('files', []):
            ret_inner = {'file_name': file.get('name'), 'mime_type': file.get('mimeType'), 'file_id': file.get('id')}
            ret_val.append(ret_inner)

        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break

    return ret_val
```

This works and I get files list, just with one problem: if I remove file on  google drive, this function still returns that removed file(s).

May be there is some timeout on Gdrive for removed files? I just can't found about this:  [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

I didn't searched good enough in docs? or I have something wrong in code?
Any help very appreciated!

Comment: According to the documentation, you might want to add `and thrashed = false` to your query.

Comment: @VirtualScooter - Thank you very much, helped a lot, if you post this as an answer, will upvote + accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, you might want to add and `thrashed = false` to your query:

```
def get_gdrive_content(folder_id):
    ret_val = []
    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = service.files().list(
                      q=f"parents = '{folder_id}' and thrashed = false",
                      fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)',
                      pageToken=page_token
                   ).execute()
        for file in response.get('files', []):
            ret_inner = {
                            'file_name': file.get('name'),
                            'mime_type': file.get('mimeType'),
                            'file_id': file.get('id')
                        }
            ret_val.append(ret_inner)
        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break
    return ret_val
```